# Why doen't this for loop work?

Tags: java, android, json, for-loop, hashmap

This is an android app that gets data from two different JSON URLs. Then I want to mix their data and put them in a map.  To do so, I use a nested for loop. But the problem is it only show YEARS and SYSTEMDATA2 and not SYSTEMDATA1.  I think my nested loop is not correct.

Does anyone know the reason?

```
for(int i = 0; i < array2System1.length(); i++){
        c1 = array2System1.getJSONObject(i);

        for(int x = 0; x < array2System2.length(); x++){

            c2 = array2System2.getJSONObject(x);

            }

        //Storing JSON item in a Variable
        valueSystem2 = c2.getString(SYSTEMDATA2);
        year = c1.getString(YEAR);
        valueSystem1 = c1.getString(SYSTEMDATA1);

         // Adding value HashMap key => value
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, valueSystem1);
         map.put(SYSTEMDATA2, valueSystem2);
         map.put(YEAR, year);


         mylist.add(map);
         list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Search.this, mylist,
                    R.layout.list_M,
                    new String[] {SYSTEMDATA1, SYSTEMDATA2, YEAR}, new int[] {
                            R.id.systemData1, R.id.systemData2, R.id.years});

         mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

result should be like 
Year  value(SYSTEMDATA2)   value(SYSTEMDATA1)

**Current problem**
it does not show one of the values. (SYSTEMDATA1 or SYSTEMDATA2)
http://i40.tinypic.com/2wqykvr.png

**NEW UPDATE**

```
        //Getting JSON Array
        JSONObject myJson1 = jsons[0];
        JSONObject myJson2 = jsons[1];
        try {
            List<Map<String, String>> listValues = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();



            JSONArray array1C1 = myJson1.getJSONArray("myDATA");
            JSONArray array2C1 = array1C1.getJSONArray(1);

            JSONArray array1C2 = myJson2.getJSONArray("myDATA");
            JSONArray array2C2 = array1C2.getJSONArray(1);

            for (int i=0; i<array2C1.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject entryJsonC1 = array2C1.getJSONObject(i);


                String val1 = entryJsonC1.getString(SYSTEMDATA1);

                String year = entryJsonC1.getString("date");


                    JSONObject entryJsonC2 = array2C2.getJSONObject(i);

                    String val2 = entryJsonC2.getString(SYSTEMDATA2);


                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, val1);
                map.put(SYSTEMDATA2, val2);
                map.put(YEAR, year);


                listValues.add(map);

            }

            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


            String[] adaptersKeys = new String[] {SYSTEMDATA1, SYSTEMDATA2, YEAR};
            int[] adapterViews = new int[] {R.id.systemData1, R.id.systemData2, R.id.years};
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MultiMainActivity.this, listValues, R.layout.list2, adaptersKeys, adapterViews);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now the result is like: YEAR SAME-VALUE SAME-VALUE

Comment: Your second for loop is ending with a `}` at line8 whereas it should end far later.

Comment: Check out my answer, you might also have another bug at the `setAdapter` method. I've also a bit optimized your code but it's still perfectible.

Comment: Can you post the contents of (at least partial): array2System1, array2System2 and explain how exactly do you want to mix them in a map please - so example map content after mixing.

Comment: @Melquiades just updated my post. please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<array2System1.length(); i++)
{
    c1 = array2System1.getJSONObject(i);
    year = c1.getString(YEAR);
    valueSystem1 = c1.getString(SYSTEMDATA1);

    for(int x=0; x<array2System2.length(); x++)
    {
        c2 = array2System2.getJSONObject(x);

        //Storing JSON item in a Variable
        valueSystem2 = c2.getString(SYSTEMDATA2);

        // Adding value HashMap key => value
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, valueSystem1);
        map.put(SYSTEMDATA2, valueSystem2);
        map.put(YEAR, year);

        mylist.add(map);
    }
}

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Search.this, mylist, R.layout.list_M, new String[] {SYSTEMDATA1, SYSTEMDATA2, YEAR}, new int[] {R.id.systemData1, R.id.systemData2, R.id.years});

// Shoudl be list and not mylist
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Or something closed to that.

Comment: thank but did not work. check the pic please [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=14y1pgo&s=5#.UpXj7JGDrwI)

Comment: Could you post your JSON here ?

Comment: In my app I have a url builder that makes a json url from a specific api. but the layout and syntax of the json is always the same. here is an example. http://api.worldbank.org/countries/ca/indicators/SP.POP.TOTL?date=2000:2008&format=json  you can change year country too. eg. ca for Canada

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all your code in the inner loop. Currently you just close the inner loop - it runs and overwrites `c2` and does nothing.

Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array2System1.length(); i++){
    c1 = array2System1.getJSONObject(i);

    for(int x = 0; x < array2System2.length(); x++){
        c2 = array2System2.getJSONObject(x);

        //Storing JSON item in a Variable
        valueSystem2 = c2.getString(SYSTEMDATA2);
        year = c1.getString(YEAR);
        valueSystem1 = c1.getString(SYSTEMDATA1);

        // Adding value HashMap key => value
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, valueSystem1);
        map.put(SYSTEMDATA2, valueSystem2);
        map.put(YEAR, year);

        mylist.add(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second for loop closes very early. it should be as follows.

```
for(int x = 0; x < array2System2.length(); x++){

            c2 = array2System2.getJSONObject(x);

        //Storing JSON item in a Variable
        valueSystem2 = c2.getString(SYSTEMDATA2);
        year = c1.getString(YEAR);
        valueSystem1 = c1.getString(SYSTEMDATA1);

         // Adding value HashMap key => value
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, valueSystem1);
         map.put(SYSTEMDATA2, valueSystem2);
         map.put(YEAR, year);
         mylist.add(map);
} // This is where it should get closed
```

Otherwise, you are just reassigning the c2 variable and loosing the other values execpt the last value. Now, you will be able to place the valueSystem1, valueSystem2 and YEAR values in map and then added to the list. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but I just checked it. It still does not show SYSTEMDATA1 and also repeats each year with each value. Please check the pic: [link](http://i43.tinypic.com/14y1pgo.png)

Comment: well the app is kinda big, but currently I am following [this tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html). but with 2 urls. if you think something is wrong, I'd post my own main activity.

Comment: wild guess - I think that HashMap should be created inside the first for loop, not on the second one and mylist.add(map) also should be outside the second for loop i.e. first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String, String>> listValues = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(.....); // Contains all the indicators
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject entryJson = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);

    // Check integrity
    if (!entryJson.hasKey("country")) throw new Exception("No 'country' key found");
    if (!entryJson.hasKey("value")) throw new Exception("No 'value' key found");
    if (!entryJson.hasKey("date")) throw new Exception("No 'date' key found");

    // Get country
    JSONObject countryJson = entryJson.getJsonObject("country");
    if (!countryJson.hasKey("value")) throw new Exception("No 'value' key found");
    String country = countryJson.getString("value");

    // Get population
    String population = entryJson.getString("value");

    // Get year
    String year = entryJson.getString("date");

    // Create a new Map
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, country);
    map.put(SYSTEMDATA2, population);
    map.put(YEAR, year);

    // Add to list
    listValues.add(map);
}

// Get the ListView
ListView Llist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

// Create a new adapter to attach this listView
String[] adapterKeys = new String[] {SYSTEMDATA1, SYSTEMDATA2, YEAR};
int[] adapterViews = new int[] {R.id.systemData1, R.id.systemData2, R.id.years};
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Search.this, listValues, R.layout.list_M, adapterKeys, adapterViews);

// Attach the adapter to the listView
Llist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is another way that should work better. I haven't tested the code as it was made in notepad. Please tell me if you have any issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is a few problems, but sounds like its close to work. First of all, should I have this code inside the `try {` ? right? and secondly, it does not accept `hasKey` and want me to cast it or change it to `has`. I changed to has, so there no error and complied but the page was empty.

Comment: and by the way, what do you mean by `SONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(.....);` ?! can you give an example based on my case. I guess this part is the reason that I get empty page.

Comment: ok i could make it working. just needed to add `list.setAdapter(adapter);` at the end. But I backed to the same problem and i begin. it shows the same value for both countries. same number. :/

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined this:

```
private static final String SYSTEMDATA1 = "value";
private static final String SYSTEMDATA2 = "value";

//you can't have 2 entries with the same key
private static final String SYSTEMDATA2_KEY = "value2";
```

The issue appears where you are creating your map:

```
// Adding value HashMap key => value
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, valueSystem1);
map.put(SYSTEMDATA2_KEY, valueSystem2);
map.put(YEAR, year);
```

[A Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value

From the docs for put() method:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.**

So you place valueSystem1 using SYSTEMDATA1 as key, which is "value" and then you place valueSystem2 using SYSTEMDATA2 as key, which is ALSO "value", so you are overwriting valueSystem1!

See the edit below...

**EDIT:**

I'm guessing that to retrieve your values, you must use keys which are "value", that's fine, but to insert in the map later, you must have unique keys. If you still have SYSTEMDATA1="value" and SYSTEMDATA2="value", add one more which you'll use to store in the map and later in the adapter:

```
//you can't have 2 entries with the same key
private static final String SYSTEMDATA2_KEY = "value2";

// Create a new Map
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(SYSTEMDATA1, val1);
map.put(SYSTEMDATA2_KEY, val2);
map.put(YEAR, year);
```

and then, when you set your adapter keys:

```
// Create a new adapter to attach this listView
String[] adapterKeys = new String[] {SYSTEMDATA1, SYSTEMDATA2_KEY, YEAR};
```

Code updated in my original answer.

Comment: Yh I see. Thanks for your explanation. I redone it by map now. but still it shows same data for both values. I guess in map it shouldn't overwrite, yh?! I got helped from @Manitoba and his latest answer. So it would be great if you check that and see why it keep overwriting values.

Comment: Update the code in your post to its current state, I'll have a look.

Comment: Please check **NEW UPDATE** bit. I kept the old whole file too, so you see that too. Thanks

Comment: In your new update I don't see the values of SYSTEMDATA1 and SYSTEMDATA2, so I assume they are both the same ("value"). Please see my update.